# Convention for set Database.SetInitializer<> in Entity Framework code-first

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to develop my first Entity Framework code-first approach. I am little bit confused regarding `Database.SetInitializer<>` -

1. Can I set multiple initializer ? i.e.

   ```
   Database.SetInitializer<Context>(new  CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<Context>());

   Database.SetInitializer<Context>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<Context>());
   ```
2. If I use only `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` initializer, and later I change database server in connection string, then will the database be created on new server?

Comment: The method says "**Set**Initializer", not "AddInitializer".  No, you cannot have more than one initializer (what would that even mean?)

Comment: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot set multiple initializer. Initializer Only insert data once in database after database created, and database creation script(internally) runs only when you will access any record of any table first time.

And before creating database EF always check first ,the database specified in connection string is present in database server. If database is not there then it will create.